# SPARK : PYTHON - unable to fit data using Logistic Regression

Tags: python, apache-spark, logistic-regression

I have a Python code working fine but when I try to use the same in SPARK, it gives the following error for FIT method :

```
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number
```

Sample data:

```
    col1  col2  col3  col4  col5  col6
0     35    78    11    78    81     0
1     30    44    13    17    51     0
2     36    73    74    74    62     0
3     60    86    11    97    24     1
```

Python Code (working):

```
# load data
data = read_csv('train.csv', names=['col1', 'col2', 'col3', 'col4', 'col5', 'col6'])
array = data.values
X = array[:,0:5]
Y = array[:,5]
```

SPARK code :

```
raw_data = train
raw_data_header = raw_data.take(1)[0]

data = raw_data.filter(lambda line: line!=raw_data_header)\
    .map(lambda line: line.split(",")).map(lambda tokens: (int(tokens[0]),int(tokens[1]),int(tokens[2]),int(tokens[3]),int(tokens[4]))).cache()

result = raw_data.filter(lambda line: line!=raw_data_header)\
    .map(lambda line: line.split(",")).map(lambda tokens: (int(tokens[5]))).cache()

data1 = data.map( lambda elem: list(elem))
result1 = result.map( lambda elem: list(elem))
X = data1
Y = result
```

The error comes in the last line when I'm trying to fit the model :

```
model = LogisticRegression()
rfe = RFE(model, 5)
fit = rfe.fit(X, Y)
```

P.S.: 
I had to convert data and result into data1 and result1 because in Spark the RDDs were not iterable and we needed data as a list of lists (and not a list of tuples)

any other way to achieve the same is also acceptable.

Comment: FYI : The iterable error which I was getting earlier was : "'PipelinedRDD' object is not iterable".

Comment: result1 == .collect() can you use collect and get your data to the driver and give a try

Comment: @Backtrack :
result1 == result.collect()
it gave :
FALSE